# User wants to set the decimal point manually in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a program calculate the circular area that the user can be set the decimals point in answer by themself. How can I do?

```
 r = int(input("Radient = ")
 y = int(input("How many point you want to show in out put = "))
 a = 2*pi*r
 print("Circular Area is %.yf" %(a))
```

Comment: At first you have to balance your parentheses, then you might want to use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: r = float(input("Radient = "))
     y = float(input("How many point you want to show in out put = "))
     a = 2*pi*r
     print("Circular Area is %.yf" %(a))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{}.format(...)` instead of `%`

Example:

```
print("{0:.{1}f}".format(3.14159, 4))
```

Comment: I want user can be set point by themself, not set by the programmer

Comment: Just take the `4` as you see in the example above from the user only using `input()`. I don't see any problem there. I have given you an idea how to have whatever you want. I can not give you full working code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.6 or above, you can try something like this using your current structure in place:

```
r = int(input("Radient = "))
y = int(input("How many point you want to show in out put = "))
a = 2*pi*r
print(f"Circular Area is %.{y}f" %(a))
```

You can read more about f-string [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b14539cbb9a7> in <module>
      2 y = float(input("How many point you want to show in out put = "))
      3 a = 2*3.141596*r
----> 4 print(f"Circular Area is %.{y}f" %(a))

ValueError: unsupported format character '.' (0x2e) at index 20

Comment: @NaraNart  You are mixing things up.   Use ` y = int(input(` instead of ` y = float(input(`

replace float with int.

Comment: oh thanks, and if a is an array in another question. How can I set code???

Comment: Not sure, but this is how you can try:

e.g if your array has 2 values.
pass it like: `print(f"Circular Area is %.{y}f and %.{y}f" %(a[0], a[1]))`

Comment: @NaraNart Feel free to upvote if you feel this solves your issue.  
Thanks.. :)